# EC2 instance Status Check failed and server stopped working

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04, aws-ec2

I am using an AWS EC2 instance (t3.xlarge) running on **Ubuntu server 18.04.6 LTS**, which was working fine. But suddenly I encountered an error where the instance status check failed **"Instance reachability check failed"** and I was not able to connect to my instance through ssh and the website attached to this server also stopped working.
I don't see any storage or Ram issue during this time.

I had to force stop and start the instance from the AWS EC2 Console to fix this issue.

Later after connecting to the server, I checked the syslog where some of the services were killed as shown in below image around the same time when the instance status check failed.

[image]

**I would like to know what is the route cause or trigger for this issue and the steps I can take to avoid such issues in the future.**

Please comment if more information is required.

Your help in solving this issue is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: Adding the output of **dmesg -T**
[click here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YaE3IK4QHjJ4LrZtRi6ZmuYkPUfSwiMcaebHL8JrRas/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What is the output of `dmesg -T`?

Comment: @AbhishekA thanks for your response, I have edited the question and added the output of dmesg -T